# CORS error on JSON parse when parsing Object full of strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors

I believe there is a JS fundamental I have forgotten, cause I keep running into this error and working around it. However, I have run into a wall this time.

I keep getting this CORS error from React when I try to `JSON.parse()` an object. What has me stumped is that I thought CORS errors where only thrown on requests. In my case, I am simply trying to parse a `stringified` string from my state.

```js
<Image className="vendor-man-image col" src={JSON.parse(this.state.sample).thumb} thumbnail />
```

The object to be parsed looks like this:

```
{
  "title":"Annotation-2020-07-08-144803.png",
  "image":"https://some-link",
  "medium":"https://some-link",
  "thumb":"https://some-link",
  "delete":"https://some-link"
}
```

Edit: I failed to mention, my object has already been `stringified`. The stringified version is what is being returned from an API.

Comment: The thing is you're passing a URL to the `Image` source, and CORS can fail there.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Image className="vendor-man-image col" src={JSON.parse(JSON.Stringify(this.state.sample)).thumb} thumbnail />
```

will solve this issue

**note**: you are still not passing text instead you are passing a object.

**this is in text format**

'{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'

---

**this is still object, which you are again trying to parse it (like parsing from object to object. thats y you got that error)**

```
{
  "title":"Annotation-2020-07-08-144803.png",
  "image":"https://some-link",
  "medium":"https://some-link",
  "thumb":"https://some-link",
  "delete":"https://some-link"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you're passing a URL to the Image source, and CORS can fail there. Make sure the URL from `thumb` is allowed for CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Please, after receiving the CORS `error`, alert or log for yourself the Image src and see where are you trying to go with it. This way you will become aware, that parsing an `"Object object"` string for a source of the target element is an **invalid url** even before it will trigger a CORS `error`.